# Create custom distance matrix function in R

Tags: r, distance-matrix

I am tasked with creating a distance matrix function based on a custom defined distance measure.
The distance measure is as follows:

```
wabs_dist = function(u, v, w){
   return( sum((abs(u-v))*w) )
}
```

Where u and v are vectors and w is a weight.

The problem I am to solve:

I am to create a distance matrix function create-dm(x,w) that returns a distance matrix for the objects in dataframe x by calling the wabs-dist(a,b,w) for all pairs of objects a and b belonging to x. If x is a data set with 4 attributes then w is a vector e.g w = c(1,1,3,2) assigned to each attribute. Yes there are already standard functions like dist() but I am to create my own here using the wabs_dist.

My solution so far:

```
create_dm = function(x, w){ #x is a dataframe
distances = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = nrow(x))
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
 for(j in 1:(i-1)){
     distances[i, j] = wabs_dist(x[i,], x[j,], w)
     distances[j, i] = distances[i, j]
   }
}
 return(distances)  
}
```

How do i implement a vector of weights because i wrote this function with the mindset of passing in just one weight but now i have to write it to accept a list. How do i do implement this function using the list of weights?

This function takes A LOT of time to run. In fact it never actually prints out the distance matrix function. I cant figure out why

An example:

Let x be a data frame containing vectors a, b and c where:
a: (1, 2)
b: (4, 5)
c: (9, 12)

w is weight vector: (0.2, 0.3)

wabs-dist(a,b,w) = 1.5
wabs-dist(b,c,w) = 3.1

create-dm(x,w)=

```
0     1.5   4.6

1.5   0     3.1

4.6   3.1   0
```

Comment: You don't explain why you put a test for j (whatever it might be) being positive. That's one of the reasons it's so slow. Also, this suggests `w` might be a constant in which case there are much faster ways to do this. PLEASE give a complete description of the problem.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want distance between all pairs of vectors in the matrix or you want every element's distance computed with every other's. If it's the latter then you are looking at `n C 2` number of computations in case of a perfect `n X n` matrix.

Comment: @42- what do you mean by constant? Its a vector for each attribute

Comment: @SaketKumarSingh between elements

Comment: In the expression `wabs_dist(x[i,], x[j,], w)` you have two single items followed by something you didn't define. It makes little sense to have w be a more than a length-1 vector which I was sloppily referring to as a constant. This question calls out for a simple example where all the objects are defined and the correct answer given.

Comment: @42- added example

Comment: You don't seem to be using R code. Are you sure you picked the correct tag?

Comment: @42- yes i am using the correct tag.

Comment: Then you have not paid sufficient attention to [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem lately. My final solution was to write it in C++ with the Rcpp package. Save this Code as dmat.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix dmat(NumericMatrix x, NumericVector w) {
  int n = x.nrow();
  NumericMatrix d = no_init_matrix(n, n);

  for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<n;j++){
      d(i,j)=sum(w*abs((x(i,_)-x(j,_))));
      d(j,i)=d(i,j);
    }

    d(i,i)=0;

  }
  return d;
}
```

Then install and load the package "Rcpp" and use `sourceCpp()` to load the function. After that you can use it like any other R function

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("path/to/file/dmat.cpp")

x <- matrix(rnorm(1500),ncol=3)
w <- 1:3

system.time(distR <- create_dm(x,w))
       User      System verstrichen 
   1.81        0.02        1.84 

system.time(distCpp <- dmat(x,w))
       User      System verstrichen 
      0           0           0

identical(round(distR,10), round(distCpp,10))
[1] TRUE
```

If you just use `identical()` without rounding it gives FALSE. Don't know why. Maybe this can be answered by someone else.

If you can use the euclidean distance instead of absolute distance you could use the package `apcluster`. This was my first solution. But the C++ solution was still faster .

Comment: how do you write the for loop in r? The for (j =i+1; j <n...) I tried writing that in r as for(j  = i+1 in 1:nrow(x) but apparently the initialization is not supported

Comment: where did you get the rcpp armadillo from. I tried installing it but its still saying that it cant find the .h file

Comment: Sorry, just copied my Code and didn't pay attention. You have to install the package `RcppArmadillo` in R if you use this header.

Comment: I edited my Code. If you use the new Code the package 'Rcpp' should be enough. With the old code you need the `RcppArmadillo` addtionally. I'm also new to Rcpp, but I was very surprised about the speed differences.